# Get child Attribute

Tags: javascript, function, attributes

I have this HTML code multiple times one after the other:

```
<li>
   <img src="path/to/my/picture.jpg" alt="my picture" />
   <span>picture title</span>
</li>
```

and I'm trying to get the path value inside the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in a variable, and also the text inside the span in another variable.

I tried this code, but it isn't working:

```
clickedLi.onclick = function() {
    var imgPath = clickedLi.firstChild;
    var pathLi = imgPath.getAttribute("src");

    var imgTitle = clickedLi.lastChild;
    var titleLi = imgTitle.data;
```

The `clickedLi` variable is only a variable that loops through an array containing all the `li` tags in the document.

So this is the complete JavaScript code I have :

```
var myLis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var liCnt = myLis.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < liCnt; i++) {
    var currentLi = myLis[i];
    currentLi.onclick = function() {                

        var imgPath = firstElementChild(this);
        var pathLi = imgPath.getAttribute("src");

        var imgTitle = lastElementChild(this);
        var titleLi = imgTitle.firstChild.data;

        var myImgDiv = document.getElementById("test");
        myImgDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>' + titleLi + '</h2>';
        myImgDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + pathLi + '" alt="' + titleLi + '">' 

    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want `imgTitle.html()`, not `.data`.

Comment: I prefer not using jQuery for this. Just personnal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.firstElementChild` and `.lastElementChild` to avoid the whitespace text nodes.

You'll need a shim if you're supporting older browsers.

```
function firstElementChild(el) {
    var child = el.firstElementChild;
    if (!child) {
        child = el.firstChild;
        while (child && child.nodeType !== 1)
            child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return child;
}

function lastElementChild(el) {
    var child = el.lastElementChild;
    if (!child) {
        child = el.lastChild;
        while (child && child.nodeType !== 1)
            child = child.previousSibling;
    }
    return child;
}
```

---

```
clickedLi.onclick = function() {
    var imgPath = firstElementChild(this); //<-- use "this", not "clickedLi"
    var pathLi = imgPath.getAttribute("src");

    var imgTitle = lastElementChild(this); //<-- use "this", not "clickedLi"
    var titleLi = imgTitle.firstChild.data;

    var myImgDiv = document.getElementById("test");

      // Concatenate the strings to do a single assignment to .innerHTML
    myImgDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>' + titleLi + '</h2>' +
                         '<img src="' + pathLi + '" alt="' + titleLi + '">';
};
```

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek: I made mistake. I reused a variable that I shouldn't have. Fixed. It would have worked in modern browsers, but not in old ones.

Comment: Ok, so I tested the second code an for whatever reason it didn't work probably a mistake I made in the rest of my code. I edited my initial post an added the rest of the JavaScript I have, where I use the two variables.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek: Is that updated code located in the same `onclick` handler? And when are you running the loop that selects the `li` elements? Have you verified that they were properly selected?

Comment: yes it is situated just after the var titleLi part. I posted the complete javascript code. But, normally it should work. I tested the li selection before.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek: Did you use `this` instead of `clickedLi` inside the handler? The only way you could use `clickedLi` in the handler would be if you invoked a function to close over that variable.

Comment: No, never, beside the two lines you suggested in your original answer.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek: There's one more issue with your updated code. You have `dmyImgDiv` instead of `myImgDiv` for the second `.innerHTML`, but also, the second `.innerHTML` assignment will overwrite the first. You should just do one assignment using a single HTML string. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xmScZ/ I'll update my answer with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

below code does what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var p = {
                onload: function() {
                    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
                    for(var i = 0, ceiling = lis.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
                        lis[i].onclick = function() {
                            var childNodes = this.childNodes;
                            for(var j = 0, ceiling2 = childNodes.length; j < ceiling2; j++) {
                                if(childNodes[j].nodeType == 1) {
                                    if(childNodes[j].nodeName == "IMG") {
                                        alert(childNodes[j].src);
                                    } else if(childNodes[j].nodeName == "SPAN"){
                                        alert(childNodes[j].innerHTML);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="p.onload()">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="path/to/my/picture1.jpg" alt="my picture" /> <span>picture title1</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="path/to/my/picture2.jpg" alt="my picture" /> <span>picture title2</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so complicated when you could use `getElementsByTagName()` on the click-on `li` tag instead of walking the child nodes yourself?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean ?

Comment: I know you can do it simpler, but hey it works...I justed wanted to give an example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
       <img src="path/to/my/picture1.jpg" alt="my picture" />
       <span>picture title 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="path/to/my/picture2.jpg" alt="my picture" />
       <span>picture title 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="path/to/my/picture3.jpg" alt="my picture" />
       <span>picture title 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can do it like this:

```
var listItems = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0, len = listItems.length; i < len; i++) {
    listItems[i].onclick = function() {
        var spanObj = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]; 
        var spanText = spanObj.textContent || spanObj.innerText;
        var imgSrc = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
        // now you have imgSrc and spanText here to do with as you please
    };
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ju9uZ/

You run this code after the document is loaded.  The simplest way to do that is to place this code right before the `</body>` tag, either inline or in an included .js file.